# why useState() is not working in react js?

Tags: reactjs

when I declare a use State variable, my react app stops working.. if I uncomment the useState then the code works fine. I don't understand what is the problem?

```
import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import useState from "react";

import "./login.scss";

const Login = (props) => {
  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    user_name: '',
    password: '',
  })


  return (
    <div className="application">
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be a few things wrong here:

1. Are you importing `useState` from react?

`import React, { useState } from "react"`

2. Are you setting value using `setText` or setting a default state value? Your current example sets default state for text as `''`
3. Are you returning text in the render method? E.g.

`return <p>{text}</p>`

4. Are you using React v16.8 or greater? If not hooks will not be available

Answer (score 0):

put curly braces around useState where you imported it like so..

```
import { useState } from "react";
```

other than that everything looks fine!

you can potentially delete the line with

```
import React from "react";
```

but it's not gonna change anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
import useState from "react";
```

Write:

```
import { useState } from "react";
```

#### Why do I need to add `{ }` to the `import`?

**Answer:** When using `import` on something that was exported with the `default` keyword - you don't need to wrap the variable name in `{ }`.

However, when using `import` on something that was exported ***not*** as `default`, you are required to wrap the variable name with `{ }` and say exactly what you want to `import`.